# Can you recover your progress after hitting Fresh Start by accident?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Is there a way to get yourself back to the point Just-Before you hit Fresh Start in Black Ops as my son didn't know that would wipe out ALL of his progress, badges, guns, etc, so I'm looking for a way for him to restore back to just before the point of hitting Fresh Start?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no legit way to bring back all your progress after selecting a **Fresh Start** from prestiging. There are two messages that appear, warning you of your choice. The second one states:

> "Are you sure? - Seriously, using Fresh Start will completely reset your progress and wipe your slate clean. There is no going back once you use Fresh Start. Are you absolutely certain that you want to start over from the beginning, as if playing the game for the very first time."

Also this Activision employee states:

> If the user selects the option "Yes, use Fresh Start" then there is no way to recover their lost stats.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackops2/comments/1jvbpl/what_happens_when_i_do_a_fresh_start/cbjc4kr)